# Update to Apple TV 6.0 has stopped certain movies from being shown from my itunes

Tags: itunes, video, appletv

After updating to the latest Apple TV software 6.0 certain seemingly random movies are now no longer available. These are all movies from my iTunes library that I ripped myself.

I can't see why its discriminating one over the other. Are there new rules for what it now shows?

They were all ripped using Handbrake (Apple TV 3 preset, mp4) and always worked before.

Also these missing movies are available to stream to my iPhone 4s and iPad 2.

Really weird, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I've made a blog post about it to help anyone with the same issues:

[Apple TV 6.0 missing movies](http://vultrix.com/post/63542846890/apple-tv-6-0-missing-movies)